# Как расшифровать этот запрос?

Tags: laravel

Как расшифровать этот запрос? $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так. Тут ваша таблица - FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE. Это каскадное удаление при удалении строки из главной таблицы автоматически удалить все связанные строки из зависимой таблицы